# C# Winforms main form sent to back

Tags: c#, winforms, overlay, bringtofront

My Winforms app has a `MainForm` and a `MainWaitForm`. For some reason I don't understand, my `MainForm` keeps being sent behind other opened windows, mainly when users click on anything when the `MainWaitForm` is showing... For example, when running the app in VisualStudio debugger mode, the wait dialog shows but VisualStudio comes right behind, instead of leaving the `MainForm` right on second level.

Here is the code of the wait form overlay :

```
static Control _parent;
public static void ShowWaitForm(Control parent) {
    _parent = parent;
    // some attempt to bring the active view to front first...
    if (_parent != null && _parent.Visible) {
      _parent.BringToFront();
    }
    else {
      MyMainForm.BringToFront();
    }
    // Make sure it is only launched once.
    if (_instance != null) {
      return;
    }
    _thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MainWaitForm.ShowForm));
    _thread.IsBackground = true;
    _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    _thread.Start(parent);
    while (_instance == null || _instance.IsHandleCreated == false) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

// the hide method
 public static void HideWaitForm() {
  // again, attempt to bring form to front...
  if (_parent != null && _parent.Visible) {
      _parent.BringToFront();
  }
  else {
      MyMainForm.BringToFront();
  }
  if (_instance != null) {
    if (_instance.InvokeRequired) {
      _instance.Invoke(new System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker(delegate {
        CloseForm();
      }));
    }
    else {
      CloseForm();
    }
  }
}

static void CloseForm() {
  _instance.Close();
  _thread = null;
  _instance = null;
}
```

Comment: because if the form is not Modal then whenever  you click anywhere else it will go to the back.. try opening your form with .ShowDialog() method try that

Comment: using `_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);` is absolutly the wrong thing to do, you are not fulfiling the STA contract because you don't have a message pump. You should get rid of the thread do do this with timers to loop and check.

Comment: You cannot steal the foreground back when your user gets tired of waiting.  Feature, not a bug.  Consider NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip() to notify him.  Only create UI on a second thread when you can do [this kind of debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/), stay out of trouble by running slow code on a worker thread and leaving up to the main thread to display UI.

Comment: @HansPassant I've tried the background worker but performance is terrific compared to main thread (the task is to sync data with DB)... Any comment on that?